# changing i386-elf-gcc configuration thread mode from single to posix

Tags: gcc

when I do `i386-elf-gcc -v` it says among other things `Thread model: single`. I want to change it to posix (without the need to specify every time I want to compile something).

I've tried to do `i386-elf-gcc --enable-threads=posix` but it thought that I want to compile something and it said `i386-elf-gcc: fatal error: no input files`.

I want that in the end when I write `i386-elf-gcc -v` it will say `Thread model: posix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you'll have to recompile the compiler. Output of `gcc -v` shows *configure* options, that is options specified during the build process of gcc itself. They are now "baked" in your installation of gcc.